# Correct pattern for DbContext use in MVC/EF6/WebApi2 application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext

I'm hoping to finally get to the very bottom of an ongoing problem with Entity Framework DbContexts. The history of my problem is that sporadically - especially when requests come in in fast succession - my DbContext throws a variety of strange errors, including the following:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>
> **System.InvalidOperationException**: Internal connection fatal error.

My MVC code is based around a basic pattern where I have a base controller, which looks like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly DbContext db = new DbContext();

    protected override void Dispose(bool Disposing)
    {
         db.Dispose();
         base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

All other controllers derive from this base controller, thereby making the DbContext available as necessary to controller actions, none of which are asynchronous. The only exception is my custom authorization, which *also* creates a DbContext upon access and is called with virtually every controller action (via attribute):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private DbContext db;

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
         db = new DbContext();
         var user = 
             db.Security.FirstOrDefault(u => 
                u.Id == actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Headers.First(h => 
                h.Key == "Id").Value);

         return (user != null);
    }
}
```

I've also experimented with the following to no avail:

- Removed all asynchronicity from my controller actions
- Removed lazy loading from DbContext and inserted explicit Include statements with each call

Looking through StackOverflow, other people appear to have had similar issues:

- [Weird race conditions when I send high frequency requests to my datacontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509498/weird-race-conditions-when-i-send-high-frequency-requests-to-my-datacontext-usin)
- [Random errors occur with per-request DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894350/random-errors-occur-with-per-request-dbcontext)

Neither answers really helped me get to the bottom of the problem, but the OP-answer of the second SO post said *("After further investigation I found out that request processing thread sometimes steals DbContext from other thread")*, but I'm not sure how this really applies.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my design? Wrapping each controller action's DbContext into a *using* block can't be right, even though [this blog](http://devproconnections.com/development/solving-net-scalability-problem) says it is - but doesn't that cause other problems, such as returning objects that are no longer attached to a DbContext (and therefore lose change tracking)...?

Comment: I was struggling with the same strange errors and in my case wrapping each of those "var user = db.Security.FirstOrDefault..." into a lock() seemed to help a little bit. I know it's just a bypass and probably giving performance drop during heavy load, but in my case it helped.

Comment: Thanks erem! If several people have this problem, I'm wondering if there is either a framework problem or a pattern problem though. These strange intermittent errors are super frustrating, and I'm really hoping for a solution that is solid. Searching through the web has only yielded workarounds so far :(

Answer (score 0):

> when requests come in in fast succession

Made me think about a a problem about a year ago so I don't think it related to EF6. However, it took me quite some time to figure it out.

Allow your databse to have more than one pending request per application. Change your connection string to **[MultipleActiveResultSets=True](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx)**

Comment: The interesting part is that my code shouldn't have multiple pending requests since I don't execute interleaved requests on DbContexts...